# undefined reference in pthread

Tags: c++, pthreads, undefined

I have this error that I am unable to figure out. I don't understand why the references are undefined. the pthread_attr_t is initialized earlier as a1, and according to the parameters, I thought it should be right. Here is my code and the error. Thanks for any help in solving this mess.

```
#include <iostream>
#include "buffer.h"
#include <pthread.h>
#include <semaphore.h>

using namespace std; 

sem_t sem_mutex;

/* create the semaphore */
//sem_init(&sem_mutex, 0, 1);
/* acquire the semaphore */
//sem_wait(&sem_mutex);

/*** critical section ***/

/* release the semaphore */
//sem_post(&mutex);

int insert(buffer_item item);
int remove(buffer_item *item);
//void *thread_entry(void *param);
//create_mutex_lock(&mutex, NULL);
//pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
//release_mutex_lock(&mutex);


int insert(buffer_item item)
{
    bool added=false;
    /* insert an item into buffer */
    item=item+1;

    cout<<"The producer added "<<item<<endl;


    if (added==true)// return 0 if successful, otherwise
        return 0; //return -1 indicating an error condition */
    else
        return -1;
}

int remove(buffer_item *item) 
{
    bool removed=false;
    item=item-1;/* remove an object from buffer and placing it in item*/

    cout<<"the consumer removed "<< item<<endl;

    if(removed==true)
        return 0;// return 0 if successful
    else
        return -1;//otherwise return -1 indicating an error condition 
}
void *thread_entry(void *param) 
{   /* the entry point of a new thread */
    pthread_t new_entry;

}

/* create the mutex lock */
//create_mutex_lock(&mutex, NULL);

/* acquire the mutex lock */
//pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);

/*** critical section ***/

/* release the mutex lock */
//release_mutex_lock(&mutex);


int main()
{
    /* 1. Answer the three command lines argument */
    pthread_t t1;
    pthread_attr_t a1;
    buffer_item buffer=0;/* 2. Initialize buffer, mutex, semaphores, and other global vars */
    buffer_item mutex=0;
    buffer_item semaphore=0;

    insert(buffer);/* 3. Create producer thread(s) */


    /* get the default attribute */
    pthread_attr_init(&a1);

    /* create a new thread */
    pthread_create(&t1, &a1, thread_entry, NULL);
//remove(*buffer);/* 4. Create consumer thread(s) */
        /* 5. Sleep */
        /* 6. Destroy mutex and semaphores */
    return 0; /* 7. Exit */
}
```

error

```
  [Linker error] undefined reference to `_imp__pthread_attr_init' 
  [Linker error] undefined reference to `_imp__pthread_create' 
  ld returned 1 exit status
```

Thanks for any help you could provide!

Comment: did you compile with `-lpthread` or `-pthread`

Comment: Also what compiler are you using?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Pthreads and undefined reference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6608379/pthreads-and-undefined-reference)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set up pthreads on windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19467455/how-to-set-up-pthreads-on-windows)

Answer (score 1):

The error you probably made is that you didn't compile with `-lpthread` or `-pthread`.

**But it doesn't matter because C++11 has native threads**

C++11 has a whole bunch of concurrency features [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread) which are actually much nicer to use than pthreads

***keep in mind that you still have to link with pthread***

Comment: @billz right but the c++11 threads play much nicer with people and have **way** more features. Is there any reason not to use them?

Comment: If you mean how to use it, then yes :)