# How to set up pthreads on windows?

Tags: c, windows, pthreads, mingw

I found an implementation for pthreads on Windows [here](http://www.sourceware.org/pthreads-win32/), but I couldn't get it to work right. Can anyone help me to install pthreads ? Like where to put DLLs, .lib, and .h files?

Also, as an environment I'm not using Visual Studio, but Codeblocks with Mingw.

I usually develop on Linux, but this project has to be on Windows, and I've already got some code implemented using pthreads, so I don't want to use Windows Threads from 'windows.h'.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The .dll can go in any directory listed in your PATH environment
variable.

The .lib file can go in any directory listed in your LIB environment
variable.

The .h files can go in any directory listed in your INCLUDE
environment variable.

Also see the [FAQs](http://www.sourceware.org/pthreads-win32/faq.html) page of the link you shared .

Read Q6, Q7, Q8.

Answer (score 7):

For Visual C++ Users (not MingW), follow this steps:

1) download "ftp://sourceware.org/pub/pthreads-win32/pthreads-w32-2-9-1-release.zip"

2) in the extraction folder, open the subfolder "Pre-built.2" and you should see the following files:

- "Pre-built.2\dll\x64\pthreadVC2.dll"  OR "Pre-built.2\dll\x86\pthreadVC2.dll"
- "Pre-built.2\lib\x64\pthreadVC2.lib"  OR "Pre-built.2\lib\x86\pthreadVC2.lib"
- "Pre-built.2\include\pthread.h"
- "Pre-built.2\include\sched.h"
- "Pre-built.2\include\semaphore.h"

3) For Visual Studio C++ x64 projects, go to project properties and add the following paths accordingly:

- Additional lib Files add "yourpath\Pre-built.2\lib\x64\"
- Additional dll files add "yourpath\Pre-built.2\dll\x64\"
- Additional include files add "yourpath\Pre-built.2\include\"

Choose the correct files according to your project build (x64 or x86).

Comment: The question was NOT to use Visual Studio so the answer doesn't help much.

Answer (score 0):

To install `gcc` on MSYS2 on Windows:

```
yes | pacman -Syu gcc
```

That's it!

By installing `gcc` on MSYS2, you automatically get `pthreads` as well.

[Here is an example that demonstrates pthreads on MSYS2 (& Linux)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7542286#65061835).

In short - the exact same code as on Linux works fine if you compile
and run it inside an MSYS2 terminal.
(Not necessarily always true, but true for the example in the link.)

##### References

- [MYS2 - Installation](https://www.msys2.org/wiki/MSYS2-installation/)
- [**pthreads** `Hello World` example that works just as fine on MSYS2
  as it does on Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7542286#65061835)

Comment: Not sure I understand what you are asking, but the package installer `pacman` here in MSYS2 is "the same" pacman as used in Arch-Linux, except of course it is the MSYS2 version of it.

Comment: I see. Well I use arch so was quite puzzled (and somewhat dazed) to see someone using the sacred program on windows ;) 
Of course, I too use windows (with basically just a couple videogames and Cygwin) , so any resource which would help we get this working ?

Comment: > *so any resource which would help [m]e get this working ?* ~ * ~ * ~

I suggest you start with the first reference in my answer - 
[MYS2 - Installation](https://www.msys2.org/wiki/MSYS2-installation/) ~ * ~ * ~  

Let me know if that works. - Once you have installed MSYS2 (which is
**much** easier than installing cygwin, I think), just open up an MSYS2 terminal and
pretend that you just opened a terminal window in (Arch-)Linux. ~ * ~ * ~  
If you get it to work, consider upvoting my answer!

Comment: Almost **any** source code I pick from a classical Linux setting (in this case C / C++ code and possibly a Linux makefile) and throw at **MSYS2** will work *without any change what so ever* to the source code. It just works. It's (almost) as if I were running genuine Linux. - Very nice indeed. ~ * ~ Although I can understand that at first you are both *puzzled* and *dazed*, in the end you should most of all be ***amazed!*** :-)

Comment: I see, but is MSYS required or can Cygwin do much the same ? Pardon my ignorance, I've no idea what it is, I just have Cygwin installed in case if I even lose my sanity trying to keep my C ISO-compliant and decide to succumb to the rich POSIX API. I'll check it out , and +1. I sure as heck need a linux environment on my windows , and best of all something like the Arch I'm used to so thanks !

PS/EDIT : MSYS2 claims to provide nativity of code, but isn't that what Cygwin does too (*though the dll*) , and same for WSL ... What marks it from these different projects ?

Comment: > *MSYS[2] required or can Cygwin do much the same ?* ~ * ~ [Compile something in <s>MinGW</s> MSYS2 and you are compiling it for Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/792142). If you have no need for Windows executables, then choose either one. I used cygwin about 5 years ago. I definitely prefer MSYS2. Side-note: MinGW and MSYS2 are synonyms - or maybe it is more correct to say that MSYS2 offers a very convenient way to install MinGW. If you ever need **native** Linux, check out [WSL](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10#step-1---enable-the-windows-subsystem-for-linux).