# I can't use pthread in window platform

Tags: c, pthreads, pthreads-win32

My env is Windows8.1 (64bit) and using Visual Studio 2010.

I did put all *.dll files in system32 , SYSWOW64(because I use win8 64bit.)

and link location where *.lib file for x64-system with VC 2010.

of course, I add additional folder lib forders.. , include folders.. etc..

but when I try compile "pthread-used" project, fatal error has occur.

**-source**

```
#include<pthread.h>
#include<stdio.h>
int doit_id,trd_id;
pthread_t trd;
void *doit(void *data){
    doit_id = (int)data;
    return 0;
}
int main(){
    trd_id=pthread_create(&trd,NULL,doit,0);
    return (0);
}
```

**-error**

```
1.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__pthread_create (referenced in function _main)
C:\Users\~program Location~ : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
```

please,help me

Comment: Are you trying to return a value in a method of return type void?

Comment: You added additional lib forder. Did you add required .lib file to the linker dependencies list?

Comment: Okuma.Scott // It just nothing. It doesn't matter return value exist or non-exist in that case.////
Alex Faber // of course, I linked *.lib files in dependencies list on VC project configure.

Comment: Okuma.Scott // also, When I set return value there, I can get that value in pthread_join.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set up pthreads on windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19467455/how-to-set-up-pthreads-on-windows)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The fact that your `main()` is looking for the name `__imp__pthread_create` indicates that you're building your project for a 32-bit target.

The 64-bit Win32 pthread library has a import symbol for `pthread_create()` with the name:

```
__imp_pthread_create
```

The 32-bit Win32 pthread libary has:

```
__imp__pthread_create
```

Note the extra underscore in the 32-bit lib - that matches the name convention that your `main()` is looking for, so it's an indication that you're building for a 32-bit target. The extra underscore is part of how x86 builds treat names in the cdecl calling convention used by the Win32 pthread library.  x64 doesn't use a cdecl calling convention (x64 has only a single calling convention) and underscores are not prepended to symbols in x64 builds.

I think you need to either download or build the 32-bit pthread library or change your project configuration to build for a 64-bit target.

Comment: It's solved! thanks to help me.
very very sooooooooooooooo~ thank you.