# How to fix undefined reference to `_imp__pthread_create'

Tags: gcc, linker, pthreads, mingw

I use MinGW on windows7 32bit.
And I can’t compile my source which uses pthread.

My code is below.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  (void)argv;
  printf("######## start \n");
#ifndef pthread_create
  return ((int*)(&pthread_create))[argc];
#else
  (void)argc;
  return 0;
#endif
}
```

Error happens as I compile it.

```
gcc -I /usr/local/include -L /usr/local/lib/libpthread.dll.a trylpthread.c
C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Temp\cc9OVt5b.o:trylpthread.c:(.text+0x25): undefined reference to `_imp__pthread_create'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I use following pthread library.

`pthreads-w32-2.8.0-3-mingw32-dev`

And here is libpthread.dll.a in /usr/local/lib

Does anyone know how to fix this problem?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set up pthreads on windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19467455/how-to-set-up-pthreads-on-windows)

Answer (score 1):

The commandline:

```
gcc -I /usr/local/include -L /usr/local/lib/libpthread.dll.a trylpthread.c
```

does not make sense.

`-L <dir>` is a linker option that directs the linker to search for required libraries
in directory `<dir>`. Thus you are telling the linker to search for required libraries in
path `/usr/local/lib/libpthread.dll.a`, which is not a directory, while on the other hand
you are not telling the linker to link any libraries at all. That is why it fails to find any
definition for `_imp__pthread_create`.

Neither does the program you have posted make sense. The lines:

```
#ifndef pthread_create
  return ((int*)(&pthread_create))[argc];
#else
  (void)argc;
  return 0;
#endif
```

say:-

If I have *not* defined a preprocessor macro `pthread_create` then compile:

```
  return ((int*)(&pthread_create))[argc];
```

else compile:

```
  (void)argc;
  return 0;
```

Well if you had defined a preprocessor macro `pthread_create`, e.g.

```
#define pthread_create whatever
```

then the code you would compile would be:

```
  (void)argc;
  return 0;
```

And since you have indeed not defined any such macro, the code you compile is:

```
  return ((int*)(&pthread_create))[argc];
```

which fails at linkage, as you see. And if that code *was* compiled with `pthread_create` so defined,
it would be:

```
  return ((int*)(&whatever))[argc];
```

Rewrite your program as:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  (void)argv;
  printf("######## start \n");
  return ((int*)(&pthread_create))[argc];
}
```

Compile with:

```
gcc -Wall -I /usr/local/include -o trylpthread.o -c trylpthread.c
```

Link with:

```
gcc  -o trylpthread.exe trylpthread.o  /usr/local/lib/libpthread.dll.a
```

Remember that when you get the program compiled and linked, the appropriate `pthreadGC??.dll`
must be found at *runtime* in one of the places where the program loader searches for dlls.

Better still, uninstall your MinGW and your `pthreads-w32-2.8.0-3-mingw32-dev` and
install a more up-to-date Windows port of GCC, e.g. [TDM-GCC](http://tdm-gcc.tdragon.net/) (simplest) or [mingw-w64](http://mingw-w64.org/doku.php). Pick the 32-bit version, if your Windows system
is 32-bit. These toolchains come with built in `pthread` support, as GCC standardly does.

Compile with:

```
gcc -Wall -o trylpthread.o -c trylpthread.c
```

Link with:

```
gcc  -o trylpthread.exe trylpthread.o  -pthread
```

(not `-lpthread`)

Comment: I can complie with `gcc -I /usr/local/include trylpthread.c /usr/local/lib/libpthread.dll.a`.  And I also can compile wihth `gcc -I /usr/local/include trylpthread.c -pthread` after reinstalled pthread by mingw-get. Thanks