# pthread installation in windows systems?

Tags: windows, multithreading, pthreads

I need to install pthread API on my windows 64-bit system so I need some help on how to get installed(pthread API)?

And it would be more helpful to me if you provide any tips/documentation relating to multithreading and how to use it on windows efficiently?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set up pthreads on windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19467455/how-to-set-up-pthreads-on-windows)

Comment: It does @SuperStormer, really appreciate